How to split a table and insert a scroll bar?
I am working on a node js web project. I added a table to the page but I want to put the first 3 columns of this table to the left and the buttons to the right. I am using Bootstrap 5.3.3 and Handlebars in my project. Here is the part of code;
<div class="table-responsive mt-4">
   <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Ürün</th>
            <th>Son Güncellenme Tarihi</th>
            {{#each sizes}}
            <th>{{this}}</th>
            {{/each}}
            <th></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {{#each spareParts}}
         <tr>
            <td>{{this.id}}</td>
            <td>{{this.item}}</td>
            <td>{{this.last_updated}}</td>
            {{#each this.quantities}}
            <td>{{this}}</td>
            {{/each}}
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                  data-bs-target="#updateModal" data-id="{{this.id}}" data-item="{{this.item}}">
               Güncelle
               </button>
               <form action="/spare-parts/delete/{{this.id}}" method="POST" style="display:inline-block;">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger px-4">Sil</button>
               </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
         {{/each}}
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>





If you put the first three columns to the left and the buttons to the right, where do you want all of the quantity columns to go?

I wanted it to be managed with a scroll bar between the first 3 columns and buttons.
